# Building a Bluetooth 4.0 messenger using Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, broadcast

I'm trying to build a messenger that requires no bluetooth pairing. The message will be broadcast by the user who adds it and can be received by the listeners in the neighborhood.

I have read in several places that Bluetooth 4.0 has support for this. However most examples involve reading from a ibeacon or a similar device.

Can I use Bluetooth 4.0 to build both a broadcaster and a receiver android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of leaving this here because it might be helpful for someone else.

Bluetooth 4.0 broadcast mode requires special hardware and it's only present in a few mobile devices. (Bluetooth peripheral mode) Therefore, instead of using bluetooth low energy, I used SDP (Service Discovery Protocol). The messages are limited to 13 characters.

However due to security restrictions, the app doesn't work for platforms above Jellybean.

Here's my development work. https://github.com/malithj/Seeder